# Symfony 2.7 retrieve root directory ANYWHERE

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I just want to ask if there's a way to retrieve the root directory of a Symfony Application **ANYHWERE**?

What I mean by anywhere is, in any file of my App.

I've searched everywhere and all I get is this:

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

Which of course works! But I can't use it in my custom classes. I need to get the root directory in one of my custom classes.

I've already read answers about DependencyInjection/Service and other stuff, but I think it's too complex/overkill to implement those just to solve my current problem.

I just want the root directory of my app, period. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you pass the root directory as a constructor parameter and tell de Dependency Injection Container (DIC) to do that? (I mean, do you get your custom class from the DIC? Or maybe you are creating the class on your own (calling ```new MyClass()``` somewhere)?

Comment: i just call static function from my class.

Comment: You need to access such low level infrastructural detail in your entities? You are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to define a constant in your `app.php` file, like this:

```
define("ROOTDIR", $kernel->getRootDir());
```

so you can then use this constant anywhere. Compared to this, a static method is overkill, too.

Comment: this is great! though i can't think of any cons for this solution. thanks! should have thought about this before

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed my answer. Indeed, it will not fit your need. Anyway, if you don't want to use dependency injection to achieve this goal because you have static methods, where do you call these static methods? In a controller? In a command? In another service? If you don't want to instanciate your class because you don't want objects with their own data, you have 2 options:

1. Get the root directory outside your class, and use it as a parameter for your static methods.
2. If your class uses static methods that means your class behave as a helper class, it is just a tool (converter, exporter, renderer...etc). So I assume that you placed all your helper classes in one directory. In this case you can create a enum class which defines constant like **root dir**, **web dir** giving the absolute paths.

Comment: I call the static methods anywhere I want to, because the function gets the config file so i need to absolute path of root dir so i can just concat /config/config_something.yml thanks! it seems @Francesco provided a concrete answer. Thank you for your ideas though.